# ActiveRecord query by arithmetic difference in attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that have `actual_amount` and `suggested_amount` attributes. I'd like to find all the records that have a percent difference of no more or no less than some threshold. Is that possible using ActiveRecord?

Currently I'm using:

```
all_rrs.select { |r| (r.suggested_amount - r.actual_amount)/r.suggested_amount >= 0.05 }.count
```

But for performance reasons I'd rather not use `select`, and some form of `where`

Note, sadly I don't know pure SQL very well, so if the answer is that it has to be written in pure SQL, will probably stick with the `select` for now (this is a very rarily used function anyhow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty much put the logic you have as a where clause of an association, and it will work.

```
all_rrs.where('(table.suggested_amount - table.actual_amount) / table.suggested_amount >= 0.05')
```